# Emacs on mac recognizing C-x as M-x

Tags: key-bindings, osx

**System Config:** macOS Sierra, Emacs v26.1 installed from emacsformacosx.com

**issue:** On a fresh install, the `C-x` key is mapped to `M-x` by default.

Is this the default behaviour?

If so, how can I change the keymapping to emulate the default mappings in Ubuntu?

Comment: Try it with no user-configuration, aka Emacs -Q.  This is probably not an Emacs problem.  Check your system preferences, keyboards, **modifier keys** and also **keyboard shortcuts** and see if something is wired differently.  And, of course, if you installed something like Karabiner, then check that too.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention, Karabiner is installed.

Comment: `C-x` and `M-x` are key *sequences* (i.e. there's no "C-x key"), so I'm presuming your issue is with *modifier* keys.  It sounds as if the modifier key that you expect to be your control key is actually mapped to meta which, as lawlist says, is almost certainly happening externally to Emacs. It's hard to tell for sure, because you don't say whether any other key sequences are affected.

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is that the modifier keys are not mapped as you expected, you can directly set the variables `mac-option-modifier`, `mac-command-modifier` and `mac-control-modifier` (and their `right-` counterparts) to either `'meta` or `'control` in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.

E.g. `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)` will make the <kbd>Command</kbd> key act as a <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.

I personally like this setup:

```
(setq mac-control-modifier 'control)
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-right-option-modifier 'control)
```